# Как установить memcached на Ubuntu 18.4 для PHP Version 7.3

Tags: php, memcache

Доброе утро.

Установил новую версию php 7.3

Сейчас надо подключить memcached.

Подскажите где искать информацию по этому поводу ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неужели в поисковике по вашему запросу ничего нет толкового?

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install php-memcached; sudo phpenmod memcached; sudo systemctl restart  php-fpm```

Comment: да у меня так не работало. Мне в ini файл надо было добавить записи для версий 7.1 7.2 7.3.

Вот что мне надо было.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2014/08/16/nginx-setup-memcache-configuration/

https://www.computersnyou.com/5828/

Answer (score 0):

Эти две ссылки полностью описывают установку memchached для версий php 7.1; 7.2;7.3

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2014/08/16/nginx-setup-memcache-configuration/

https://www.computersnyou.com/5828/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]